# How do you use the ADDRESS function on a sheet other than the one it’s written on?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I’m trying to use =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,Outer!A2:A,0),2)), which should be taking from the Outer sheet, but it is understandably instead taking from the sheet it is on. Is there a way to take address from a different sheet or would I need to use a middle man?

Answer (score 0):

To get the value in column `Outer!B2:B` in the first row where column `Outer!A2:A` matches the value in `A2`, use `vlookup()`, like this:

```
=vlookup(A2, Outer!A2:B, columns(Outer!A2:B), false)
```

...or `filter()`, like this:

```
=single( filter(Outer!B2:B, Outer!A2:A = A2) )
```

To answer your question, you can get the address of the cell on the `Outer` sheet and then retrieve the value with `indirect()` with this convoluted formula:

`=indirect( "Outer!" & address( row(Outer!A2) + match(A2, Outer!A2:A, 0) - 1, column(Outer!B2) ))`

The `indirect()` function is a volatile, so it will get recalculated *every* time *any* value in the spreadsheet is edited, which hurts spreadsheet performance. I would not recommend the `indirect(address())` pattern for much anything.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to apply the first formula to find A2’s corresponding value in the C column instead?

Comment: Replace the two instances of `Outer!A2:B` with `Outer!A2:C`.